# Data base One To Many Relationship Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have 3 tables in my DB; Transactions, transaction_details, and accounts - basically as below.

transactions :

- id
- details
- by_user
- created_at

trans_details :

- id
- trans_id (foreign key)
- account_id
- account_type (Enum -[c,d])
- amount

Accounts :

- id
- sub_name

In each transaction each account may be creditor or debtor. What I'm trying to get is an account statement (ex :  bank account movements) so I need to query each movement when the account is type = c (creditor) or the account type is = d (debtor)

trans_id, amount, created_at, creditor_account, debtor_account

Update : I tried the following  query but i get the debtor column values all Null!

```
SELECT transactions.created_at,trans_details.amount,(case WHEN trans_details.type = 'c' THEN sub_account.sub_name END) as creditor,
(case WHEN trans_details.type = 'd' THEN sub_account.sub_name END) as debtor from transactions
JOIN trans_details on transactions.id = trans_details.trans_id
JOIN sub_account on trans_details.account_id = sub_account.id
GROUP by transactions.id
```

After the help of @Jalos I had to convert the query to Laravel which also toke me 2 more hours to convert and get the correct result :) below is the Laravel code in case some one needs to perform such query
I also added between 2 dates functionality

```
 public function accountStatement($from_date,$to_date)
    {
        $statemnt = DB::table('transactions')
        ->Join('trans_details as credit_d',function($join) {
                            $join->on('credit_d.trans_id','=','transactions.id');
                            $join->where('credit_d.type','c');
                        })
        ->Join('sub_account as credit_a','credit_a.id','=','credit_d.account_id')
        ->Join('trans_details as debt_d',function($join) {
                            $join->on('debt_d.trans_id','=','transactions.id');
                            $join->where('debt_d.type','d');
                        })
        ->Join('sub_account as debt_a','debt_a.id','=','debt_d.account_id')
        ->whereBetween('transactions.created_at',[$from_date,$to_date])
        ->select('transactions.id','credit_d.amount','transactions.created_at','credit_a.sub_name as creditor','debt_a.sub_name as debtor')
        ->get();
        return response()->json(['status_code'=>2000,'data'=>$statemnt , 'message'=>''],200);
    }
```

Comment: You have to use sql? You could achieve it with other programming languages like pgplsql or python

Comment: @Kevin why do you think the tagged tools are ill-suited to this task?

Comment: @AliAdil See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a homework question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `transactions` table denotes transaction records, while your `accounts` table denotes account records. Your `trans_details` table denotes links between `transactions` and `accounts`. So, since in a transaction there is a creditor and a debtor, I assume that `trans_details` has exactly two records for each transaction:

```
select transactions.id, creditor_details.amount, transactions.created_at, creditor.sub_name, debtor.sub_name
from transactions
join trans_details creditor_details
on transactions.id = creditor_details.trans_id and creditor_details.account_type = 'c'
join accounts creditor
on creditor_details.account_id = creditor.id
join trans_details debtor_details
on transactions.id = debtor_details.trans_id and debtor_details.account_type = 'd'
join accounts debtor
on debtor_details.account_id = debtor.id;
```

[image]

EDIT

As promised, I am looking into the query you have written. It looks like this:

```
SELECT transactions.id,trans_details.amount,(case WHEN trans_details.type = 'c' THEN account.name END) as creditor,
(case WHEN trans_details.type = 'd' THEN account.name END) as debtor from transactions
JOIN trans_details on transactions.id = trans_details.trans_id
JOIN account on trans_details.account_id = account.id
GROUP by transactions.id
```

and it is almost correct. The problem is that due to the group-by MySQL can only show a single value for each record for creditor and debtor. However, we know that there are exactly two values for both: there is a `null` value for creditor when you match with debtor and a proper creditor value when you match with creditor. The case for debtor is similar. My expectation for this query would have been that MySQL would throw an error because you did not group by these computed case-when fields, yet, there are several values, but it seems MySQL can surprise me after so many years :)

From the result we see that MySQL probably found the first value and used that both for creditor and debtor. Since it met with a creditor match as a first match, it had a proper `creditor` value and a `null` `debtor` value. However, if you write bullet-proof code, you will never meet these strange behavior. In our case, doing some minimalistic improvements on your code transforms it into a bullet-proof version of it and provides correct results:

```
SELECT transactions.id,trans_details.amount,max((case WHEN trans_details.type = 'c' THEN account.name END)) as creditor,
max((case WHEN trans_details.type = 'd' THEN account.name END)) as debtor from transactions
JOIN trans_details on transactions.id = trans_details.trans_id
JOIN account on trans_details.account_id = account.id
group by transactions.id
```

Note, that the only change I did with your code is to wrap a `max()` function call around the case-when definitions, so we avoid the `null` values, so your approach was VERY close to a bullet-proof solution.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d468dc/10/0

[image]

However, even though your thought process was theoretically correct (theoretically there is no difference between theory and practice, but in practice they are usually different) and some slight changes are transforming it into a well-working code, I still prefer my query, because it avoids `group by` clauses, which can be useful, if necessary, but here it's unnecessary to do `group by`, which is probably better in terms of performance, memory usage, it's easier to read and keeps more options open for you for your future customisations. Yet, your try was very close to a solution.

As about my query, the trick I used was to do several joins with the same tables, aliasing them and from that point differentiating them as if they were different tables. This is a very useful trick that you will need a lot in the future.

Comment: thanks for your query, please can you check the update

Comment: @AliAdil your try seems to overcomplicate things. Why would you group by transactions when there is a single creditor and debtor for each transaction? Also, what was the result of the query I have shown in my answer?

Comment: your query is not running lot of unknown columns and fields , i don't have creditor_details or creditor, debtor columns

Comment: @AliAdil creditor_details is an alias for trans_details. So, you have creditor_details columns, as they are practically trans_details columns.

Comment: @AliAdil please share the error message you had when you executed my query.

Comment: @AliAdil there was a typo in my answer, fixed it. Please try it out.

Comment: sorry for that plz check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d468dc/2

Comment: @AliAdil what was the result when you executed my query? I'm happy to check your query *after* at least you prove that you took my answer into account.

Comment: @AliAdil you are welcome! As about your fiddle. As about your query, the problem with it was that there are two rows to join to the details table. Will have to go now, when I come back, I will probably look into it in a more detailed manner.

Comment: @AliAdil sorry for not reacting earlier. So, the link you have sent contains case-when selections and you were pretty close. I will edit my answer to reflect on it.

Comment: @AliAdil as promised, analyzed your query and made it work. You can see it in my answer, which was recently edited.

Comment: Thank you very much, you really made my day and I really learned new query from yours which I never used before